# What's the process and details for Azure DevOps ramp down/transfer?

Tags: azure-devops

We were using Azure DevOps for our backlog, source code and pipeline. But our team will be released. Which means the backlog, source code will not be used any more because our Project is terminated. so what's the process and details to perform on the Azure DevOps?

Comment: What's that mean for ramp down the Azure DevOps? Do you mean you purchased some subscriptions/licenses and for now you want to unsubscribe them?

Comment: Our team/project will be terminated, all the things on Azure DevOps will not be used any more. team members licenses will be removed also. So do we just leave backlog/source code/pipeline there which will be achived months later? for this situation, is there any cost to companywide? or delete project in VSTS is enough?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can change the billing from Organization Settings ->  billing page (https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_settings/billing).

If the users have VS subscriptions, once removed the licenses for the team members, then it will not cause any cost any more on that organization.

If you purchased other resources such as `Azure Pipelines`, `Azure Artifacts`, extra `USER LICENSES`, etc, then you just need to remove them by changing the billing or remove the billing directly from that organization.

After removing the billing, no any cost will be caused by that organization. Please see [Pricing for Azure DevOps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/azure-devops-services/) and [Quickstart: Manage paid access for users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/buy-basic-access-add-users?view=azure-devops) for details.

For the existing projects you can freely delete them as needed.

Comment: @Vicky Have you resolved the issues? is the reply helps? Any update here?